# JavaScript object structure: how to access inner field with 'complex.key'

Tags: javascript

Given an object like this:

```
var obj = {
"name":"JonDoe",
"gender":"1",
"address":{
    "phone":"1"
    }
}
```

I know you can have such things :

```
    console.log(obj['name']); // returns 'JonDoe'
```

My problem comes with the inner structure 'address', whose 'phone' inner field I would like to target with `obj['address.phone']` but it returns instead *undefined* where all level 1 field return the matching value.

I am quite sure you could do it with some (de)serialisation function or any json lib, but I am am wondering if there's a smart way to list all inner structures like 'address' **with no preliminary knowledge of which field I am going to target** (like obj[field]).

Comment: Tried `obj["address"]["phone"]`?

Answer (score 3):

Do:

```
var phone = obj.address.phone;
```

Bracket notation is typically used when using variables as the property name. If you know the properties, feel free to use dot notation (seen above)

Comment: I prefectly agree with that soluion for overall purpose... but not for mine. And my bad : I haven't focused enough on the important matter here :  **with no preliminary knowledge of which field I am going to target **. It means I don't know in advance what my field will be : either level 1 field, or deeper complex field.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
var addresses = [];

for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        addresses.push(obj[key]['address']);
    }
}

console.log(addresses);
```

For more complex object property querying use this library [linq.js - LINQ for JavaScript](http://linqjs.codeplex.com/)

#### Update

If you want to list all address phones no matter how deep they are try recursive scanning:

```
var phones = [];

var scan = function(obj) {
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            if (key == 'address') {
                phones.push(obj[key]['phone']);
            }
            else if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
                scan(obj[key]);
            }
        }
    }
};

scan(obj)
console.log(phones);
```

Comment: Olim, I didn't know that method so I had a look; unfortuntaley, and unless I read wrong, I can only say I can use direct adressing and not : obj.hasOwnProperty(field) will return false if field = 'address.phone' (for ex.), only allowing me to skip it. I also looked into the 'in' method, but I think the problem is the same. Correct me in case I am wrong

Comment: @Marvin, I've updated my answer. Let me know if it is not what you want.

Comment: It's  closer, but here again, the structure can be very complex with many embedded structures and inner levels. Thus, I would have to test for many of it, and in that case, that would be quite a heavy process for something that looks quite basic to me. But from your code, I think I could do stg, since I should be able to use recursivity here for both sides of the assignation... I have to think about it. That's an interesting track I will follow. I'll tell you If I manage to make it work and how